# How to solve "No best type was found for the switch expression" for objects?

Tags: c#, c#-11.0

I have the following:

```
private static readonly IDictionary<Type, int> types = new Dictionary<Type, int>() {
    { typeof(Category), 1 },
    { typeof(Product), 2 },
};


public async Task<T> GetItemAsync<T>(int number, CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    var t = types[typeof(T)] switch
    {
        1 => await service.GetCategoryAsync(number, ct),
        2 => await service.GetProductAsync(number, ct),
        _ => throw new NotSupportedException()
    };

    return t;
}
```

But I get the following compiler error:

> No best type was found for the switch expression

How can I solve this problem?

Secondly, how can I return a concrete object (`Category`, `Product`, etc) as `T`?

**EDIT**

```
var t = types[typeof(T)] switch
{
    1 => (T)(object)(await service.GetCategoryAsync(number, ct)),
    2 => (T)(object)(await service.GetProductAsync(number, ct)),
    _ => throw new NotSupportedException()
};
```

I did the above change and I do not get an compiler errors anymore. But is this boxing really necessary?

Comment: What type do `service.GetCategoryAsync` and `service.GetProductAsync` return?

Comment: They return `Category` and `Product` respectively.

Comment: Since you are using C#11, have you tried completely ditching that highly questionable map and instead simply doing `var t = T switch { Category => await..., Product => await..., _ => throw ... };` ?

Comment: @MikeNakis I get the error: `T` is a type, which is not valid in the given context.

Comment: OK, how about `var t = typeof(T) switch { ...`  (Sorry, I have no compiler available right now)

Comment: This sounds like an [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You're asking us to issues with your solution to a problem, instead of asking help with the problem. What you are trying to do (variable return type) is making life hard: it's difficult to read and maintain. Please tell us the _actual_ problem you are trying to solve. _Why_ do you need this?

Comment: _"But is this boxing really necessary?"_ - there is no boxing here happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a switch expression with when-clauses to avoid the mapping dictionary. Also, you can cast the result to `T` after casting to the neutral type `object`.

```cs
public async Task<T> GetItemAsync<T>(int number, CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    return typeof(T) switch {
        var t when t == typeof(Category) => (T)(object)await service.GetCategoryAsync(number, ct),
        var t when t == typeof(Product) => (T)(object)await service.GetProductAsync(number, ct),
        _ => throw new NotSupportedException(),
    };
}
```

---

Using a switch over a generic type defies the purpose of generics. Maybe a better approach would be to make the service itself generic.

```cs
public async Task<T> GetItemAsync<T>(int number, CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    var service = new Service<T>();
    return await service.GetAsync(number, ct);
}
```

Comment: `(T)(object)` clever... but I wouldn't approve it if I'd see this in a PR 

Comment: @JHBonarius, yes. I tend to a non-generic approach (like yours) or a more consequently designed generic approach not requiring switches.

Answer (score 1):

Generics are resolved compile time, while the code seems to want to do this at runtime. That doesn't make much sense.
You can do all kind of weird things with type hiding and discriminated unions. But why would you?

Don't make life hard. If you want to forward the service interface:

```cs
public Task<Category> GetCategoryAsync(int number, CancellationToken ct = default) =>
    service.GetCategoryAsync(number, ct);
public Task<Product> GetProductAsync(int number, CancellationToken ct = default) =>
    service.GetProductAsync(number, ct);
```

Much easier to read and easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the error is from using `var` instead of a base type, and so the pattern matcher doesn't know how to infer the type or if it matches the return type.

Here's an example where I use the `object`, which all classes have as a base type. I modified the `var t` to use `object t`, and then I changed the return type to `Task<object>`:

```
    public async Task<object> GetItemAsync<T>(int number, CancellationToken ct = default)
    {
        object t = types[typeof(T)] switch
        {
            1 => await service.GetCategoryAsync(number, ct),
            2 => await service.GetProductAsync(number, ct),
            _ => throw new NotSupportedException()
        };

        return t;
    }
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#declaration-and-type-patterns) shows the type checking using an actual value, not just the `T` expression, though I'm no expert in pattern matching, yet.

Comment: [Here's](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4L1aas) my playground I was using.

Comment: But this is different: instead of returning a static type, you return an anonymous type. You need some typecasting somewhere, and/or dynamic resolving of situations. But we're missing the context, as the OP isn't specifying it.

Comment: True, it doesn't solve the problem of the initial question, but it gives the reason why the compiler doesn't like it.